# communication system

Tags: near-future

What COMMUNICATION SYSTEM would be most effective for emergency messages underwater and deep inside mountain habitats? How would the sound energy be effected by moving through air, water or solid rock.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Underwater? The acoustic coupling between water and air is awful, very little energy would get through. How far away are the cities and how are they connected, if tunnels then what sort of network and diameter? You can [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to worldbuilding, enjoy.

Comment: How far away are these deep mountain strongholds away from the ocean seawater? Cos there is such a thing as coastal saltwater intrusion but still underwater acoustics will surely be affected beyond whatever a layman can describe. At the moment this question is _way too broad_ to even begin to provide an answer. Are you asking about 'advanced tech', 'typical fantasy story tech' or only purely scientific acoustic communisitic channels. Eg are there cables/fiber optics or other 'intermediary' communication routes or is it all purely acoustics though water/rock mediums?...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Multi-modal

RF comms work well in the air, but do not work underwater. Acoustic comms are possible in the water, but do not couple into the air. No comms system really works through solid rock, but you could drill a hole and lay wire or fibre.

So use all the above.

Put a buoy floating on the surface of the water, and the undersea base can send acoustic communications to the buoy. Since part of the buoy is above the water, it could repeat the signal in RF in the air, which could travel to land. A repeater on the surface of the mountain can take in the RF, and convert it to a signal on the wire.

### This is basically the Internet

Standard internet comms are mode-agnostic. I can send an email from my phone, which goes over RF to the cell tower, before being sent via fibre to someone's home, where they receive it over wifi (RF again). Acoustic is not a big player on the internet today, mostly because very few people live underwater.

Answer (score 3):

**Cables?**

[image: cables]

https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2010/11/before-underwater-internet-cables-the-first-submarine-telegraph-line/67130/

Undersea cables are a technology that is 150 years old and going strong.  It is hard to beat a cable for carrying a signal.

Your enclaves of survivors are connected by cable.  Maybe they are retro copper cables wrapped in gutta percha like the one they are laying down behind the depicted ship (note sailing ship in the distance!).  Maybe they are Google Fiber cables that show you ads promoting Google Fiber every time you want to watch some Kpop or clips of Chuck Norris movies; first the Google Fiber.

But cables; yes, the cables.  They are good for what your people need.

Comment: yeah, fiber optic cables.

Answer (score 2):

[Extremely low frequency radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency) is already used by the navies of the US, Russia and China to communicate with their respective submarine fleet.

Similar [low frequency radio systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through-the-earth_mine_communications) have been used by some underground mines and cavers.

Answer (score 1):

Sound travels very well through water and rock, better than through air.  The problem may be between these and air.

Low frequencies have long range in water, which is why whales use low frequencies.

The problem with humans producing sound in water is that we use air over our vocal cords.  However, once sound is produced, water is a good medium.